# Session makes no updates in the method sess_write() at the first time

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session, activerecord

I’ve a big problem in my application. The first page which does a insert in $CI->session->userdata doesn’t update the database, but the update method of Active Record returns 1 (or true). So, my session wasn’t recorded in database at the first time, but on a second attempt was recorded.

I did a test on the method sess_write() in the CI_Session class, selecting with the Active Record the record of the current session. The result shown by the Active Record was the same of updated, but when I checked at the database with PHPmyadmin, the record of this session in ci_session table wasn’t upgraded.

Exemple:

```
function sess_write()
 {

//Previous userdata:  array(x:'abc')

...

$this->CI->db->where('session_id', $this->userdata['session_id']);
$this->CI->db->update($this->sess_table_name, array('last_activity' => $this->userdata['last_activity'], 'user_data' => $custom_userdata)); 
//Was updated array(x:'abc',  y:'123')


echo "<pre>";
$result = $this->CI->db->query('SELECT * FROM (`ci_sessions`) WHERE `session_id` =  "' . $this->userdata['session_id'] . '"', false, true);
$result = $result->result_array();
echo "Resultado Query=";
print_r($result[0]['user_data']); 
//Was printed array(x:'abc',  y:'123')
echo "</pre>";

...

//In ci_session in database was shown array(x:'abc'). Should be array(x:'abc', y:'123').


}
```

Update:

```
function sess_write(){

...

$this->CI->db->query('SELECT * FROM (`ci_sessions`) WHERE `session_id` =  "' . $this->userdata['session_id'] . '"', false, true);
$result->result_array();

sleep(1); // I have inserted this sleep for tests, and the problem was gone.

$this->_set_cookie($cookie_userdata);

}
```

For tests, I have inserted a sleep(1); after the update() of the session in the sess_write() function, and the system worked perfectly updating the session.

Which may be related to this? What possible solution I could use?

Comment: That sounds rather impossible! Just to confirm, you refreshed PHPMyAdmin page right? Have you made any other changes to session library in system or have you extended Sessions anywhere?

Comment: You can also check what is returned from sess_read in 
Session __construct()
If it returns false, then sess_create will be called, which will reset user_data in database

Comment: sess_read() are returning true, so the database wasn't reseted. I already suspected that, since the data were not reseted, they just remaing as they were in defined at login.

Comment: I'm just extended CI_Sessions, but this doesn't changed the operation.

Comment: For tests, I have inserted a sleep(1); after the update() of the session in the sess_write() function, and the system worked perfectly updating the session.

Which may be related to this?